# submit php variables with javascript (link?)

Tags: php, ajax

I'm creating a browser based game and at the moment I'm designing the script that updates the position of my character when he/she clicks on a different part of the map.

I am using a bit of ajax to do this which send a request to a php file called position_update.php. But for it to work I need to send two values along with it so it knows what the new position is, how do I do this? Below is my link that send the request to php file.

```
<a onClick="positionUpdate();"><img src="images/transparent.gif" border="0" /></a>
```

As a note, I'm using the php $_GET super global to retrieve the values when they're sent.

Thanks, Stanni

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to hit the URL:

```
position_update.php?var1=val1&var2=val2
```

PHP will parse the get string into $_GET

Answer (score 1):

BTW, you should ensure that degrades gracefully by having an equivalent href value that works for non-js users.

Comment: IIRC, his application uses AJAX to render/update a tile-based game. So without javascript enabled, the user would not be able to play the game anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to encode the URL string, use the javascript function **encodeURL()**:

```
sUrl = encodeURL("position_update.php?dir="+sDir+"&dist="+sDist);
```

And remember that in a client-server architecture, do not put too much implicit trust in the client. All of the application logic that handles game mechanics and rules enforcement should be contained in the server-side component.

A few years ago there was a really popular game called TetriNET (multiplayer online Tetris) that was designed without these security considerations. It took me about 3 days to crack the communication protocol and basically draw on other players' screens using server commands for creating/clearing blocks. It made cheating very easy using just a simple proxy.

So don't let the client *'tell' the server* where the player is. Use the client only to display the interface, collect input, and display output. So have the client tell the server where the player *'wants' to move* (direction, how far, etc.), and then have *the server* calculate the player's position based on what moves the player is legally allowed to make and his previous position.