# Updating database with php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, variables

Below is my script that updates my characters position in my database:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function positionUpdate(){
var word = document.getElementById('test').value;
var queryString = "?word=" + word;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "new_position.php" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
alert(queryString);
}
</script>
```

Next is the script that tells the above script to run but I need to send two variables across to it so it knows what to update.

```
<a onClick="positionUpdate();"><img src="images/transparent.gif" border="0" /></a>
```

The link above is used multiple times so I need to send the values with that and not put the variables in the script at the top otherwise they would always be the same.

As a note I am using the php GET function to retrieve the variables in position_update.php

Thanks, tanni

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719880/submit-php-variables-with-javascript-link

Comment: If you actually read carefully its two different questions, I made this one after I realized I asked the wrong question first.

Comment: Ok, no problem - just looked quite similar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function positionUpdate(var1, var2){
    var word = document.getElementById('test').value;
    var queryString = "?word=" + word + "&var1=" + var1 + "&var2=" + var2;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "new_position.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
    alert(queryString);
}
</script>
```

and

```
<a onClick="positionUpdate('val1', 'val2');"><img src="images/transparent.gif" border="0" /></a>
```

Is that what you mean?  It seems like a fairly basic question...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question.

Why don't you just pass the variables as function parameters to positionUpdate?

Maybe you could explain in a bit more detail what you are trying to accomplish.